# Efficiently generate a very large Excel file in .NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, out-of-memory

I need to generate a very large Excel file from an ASP.NET MVC site, but am running into memory limitations using the Open XML SDK. Is there a memory efficient way to generate such a file?

For reference, I'm trying to generate a spreadsheet with about 500,000 rows with 20 columns each. The data set itself fits into memory just fine, but the Open XML SDK quickly eats up all of my available memory.

Comment: [First hit on Google](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/brian_jones/archive/2010/06/22/writing-large-excel-files-with-the-open-xml-sdk.aspx). You want the SAX strategy.

Comment: Why are you putting that much data in to Excel, are you really presenting that much data? Can you switch to a database like SqlExpress?

Comment: Frédéric - I searched for quite a while without finding that. I'll check it out, thanks.

Comment: Scott - it's for exporting purposes.

Comment: @BrianVallelunga Exporting to what? Does the thing that is importing the data only accepting Excel files? Will it accept CSV files? Will it accept XML? Don't get stuck between [choosing a shoe or glass bottle](http://weblogs.asp.net/alex_papadimoulis/408925)!

Comment: Scott just said this but I think it bears highlighting, can your client accept CSV files? Excel is able to open them (and is often, I believe, the default application to do so, so users might not even notice), it's a mode widely used format (Excel has advantages, obviously, but CSV is preferable if it does what you need), and most importantly, you can theoretically push it down the client in real time, without needing any in-memory caching. Since you don't need closing tags, you can just write it directly to the output stream without too much thought. I'd definitely look into that option.

Comment: Yes, OOXML SDK is very slow when dealing with large file, say > 10000 rows of Excel data

Comment: We have a similar problem. In our case, the exported data is being "imported" by accountants. And they don't support many formats.

Answer (score 3):

You can use Open XML SDK in reasonably efficiently way, the trick is to use the [OpenXmlWriter](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/documentformat.openxml.openxmlwriter?view=openxml-2.8.1) class (in [this CodeProject article](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/877791/How-to-Create-Large-Excel-File-using-Openxml) you have more details)

I had a memory issue generating a file of 91 columns x 164,000 rows. Using OpenXmlWriter I went from 2GB of RAM consumption to 120MB, enough for me :-)

Seeing it with a code example:

Standard (and unoptimized) way:

```
// Table header
Row headerRow = new Row();
foreach (string fieldName in fields)
{
    Cell cell = new Cell();
    cell.DataType = CellValues.String;
    cell.CellValue = new CellValue(fieldName);
    headerRow.AppendChild(cell);
}
sheetData.AppendChild(headerRow);

// Table rows
while (dataReader.Read())
{
    Row dataRow = new Row();

    foreach (string fieldName in fields)
    {
        Cell cell = new Cell();
        cell.DataType = CellValues.String;
        cell.CellValue = new CellValue(reader[fieldName].ToString());
        dataRow.AppendChild(cell);
    }

    sheetData.AppendChild(dataRow);
}
```

OpenXmlWriter way:

```
using (var writer = OpenXmlWriter.Create(worksheetPart))
{
    writer.WriteStartElement(new Worksheet());
    writer.WriteStartElement(new SheetData());

    // Table header
    writer.WriteStartElement(new Row());
    foreach (string fieldName in fields)
    {
        writer.WriteStartElement(new Cell() { DataType = CellValues.String });
        writer.WriteElement(new CellValue(fieldName));
        writer.WriteEndElement();        
    }
    writer.WriteEndElement(); //end of Row tag

    // Table rows
    while (dataReader.Read())
    {
        writer.WriteStartElement(new Row());

        foreach (string fieldName in fields)
        {
            writer.WriteStartElement(new Cell() { DataType = CellValues.String });
            writer.WriteElement(new CellValue(dataReader[fieldName].ToString()));
            writer.WriteEndElement();        
        }

        writer.WriteEndElement(); //end of Row tag
    }

    writer.WriteEndElement(); //end of SheetData
    writer.WriteEndElement(); //end of worksheet
    writer.Close();
}
```